# Lambda Expression - How to provide values to where clause from an IEnumerable<Object>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

I've a supplier table filled with supplier objects, supplierID is the primary key here. I've to find all products supplied by these suppliers. Since there is a many-many relationship, I've a bridge table in between SupplierProducts, with supplierID and productID as a composite primary key.

I've used lambda function to get an `IEnumerable<SupplierProducts>` for a particular supplier. Now, I'd like to query the products table to find all products that are in `IEnumerable<SupplierProducts>`. I don't want to use a `foreach()` to populate the products table, but rather an 'in' like lambda expression.

I'm sure this must have been answered earlier, but unfortunately after trying for fifteen minutes, I've not been able to find a clear solution. I've looked into `contains()` and `any()` functions. Here is my code:

```
IEnumerable<SupplierProducts> supplierProducts = db.SupplierProducts.Where(w => w.SupplierID == supplierID).ToList();
IEnumerable<Products> products = db.Products.Where(w => w.ProductID.contains(supplierProducts.productID)).ToList();
```

Comment: You could try swapping `w.ProductID` and `supplierProcducts.productID`, for example, `db.Products.Where(w => supplierProducts.productID.Contains(w.ProductID)).ToList();`

Comment: @KeyurPATEL supplierProducts is an IEnumerable and doesn't give me access to productID directly, unless I use First() or similar methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are pretty close: all you need to do is selecting IDs, and then using `Contains`, like this:

```
var supplierProductIds = db.SupplierProducts
    .Where(w => w.SupplierID == supplierID)
    .Select(p => p.productID)
    .ToList(); // You could get better performance without ToList
IEnumerable<Products> products = db.Products
    .Where(w => supplierProductIds.Contains(w.ProductID))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt suggestion. I've tried this already, but it gives me an error ''System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Application.Models.SupplierProducts>' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Contains<TSource>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSource>, TSource)' has some invalid arguments'.

Comment: @SJaka That was before you added a `Select()`, though, right?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, Why you're converting the first assignment to a list ? leave it `IQueryable<>`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight My bad, I noticed that after I posted the comment. Yes, it does let me select correctly now. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @OrelEraki That would work, too. I wanted to keep as much of OP's code as possible, so I kept `ToList()`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, Understood +1. It will be nice if you'll add it as a Note\Mark for performance wise.

Answer (score 0):

If you have constructed you model correctly you should have the virtual property for Products in Supplier class

```
public virtual ICollection<Product> Products {get; set;}
```

and this would have made your task easier:

```
 db.Suppliers.Where(s => s.Id == supplierID).Select(s => s.Products)
```